# Linux command to make a port to listen

Tags: linux, command, port

I tried this command nc -l "port number". But it is not working out for my test. Can anyone let me know which command should i use.

Comment: can you rephrase your question? if you meant "listen", you are using the right command

Comment: `nc` will accept connections to the port, so the port is not actually blocked. It is just that other programs are prevented from listening on the same port as nc. Also, if a program connects to `nc` and then disconnects, it will exit and stop listening on that port.

If your intention is to block all connections to a port, then `iptables` would be the right tool to use.

Comment: @sanjak79 Okay. This command is used to make a port to listen. Correct only. But When i'm installing setup i should use this busy port. It should not accept this port right? Because it is already in use. But in my case it accepts and proceeds with the next step. After that also I checked with this command "netstat -nap | sudo grep portnumber". Still it is in use only.

Comment: @skmrx. THank you. I have no idea about iptables. How should i use it ?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with `iptables` as well, but I think you can figure it out after going through http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/ . You'll most likely need root permissions to use it though.

There may be other ways to do what you want without blocking the port. If you can give more details about the actual problem you're trying to solve, you might be able to get some more solutions to it.

Comment: @skmarx. Thanks for the help. First I need to make this port 9090 busy. Then I need to use this port to install setup. While asking the input for port I should enter this(9090) port. Expected result is that port is in use so again it should ask to enter available port number. But the issue am facing is that it accepts this(9090) port and proceeds with the next step. I checked using this command "netstat -nap | sudo grep 9090". Still it is in use only. But I can able to move next step. This should not happen.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use non listening port which is greater than 1024. Let us try with below command

```
 nc -lp 2468
```